# jQuery UI ToolTip strange behavior of position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qg43v53k/24/

I try connect tooltip to table cells, table have width more than width of window. The width of tooltips of cells out of screen is too small.
How can I fixed this.

**html code**

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
        <td class="tooltip" title="In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips and jQuery UI tooltips." style="width:200px;">Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
 $('.tooltip').tooltip({
            position: {
                my: "center top",
                at: "center bottom",
            },
            content: function() {
                 var element = $( this );
                 if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                     return element.attr( "title" );
                 }
                 if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
                     return element.attr( "alt" );
                 }
             },
    });
```

**css**

```
table{
    margin-top:50px;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:1400px;
}
table td{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might achieve what you want to do is to set the `width` of the tooltips explicitly when they are opened.

You can do this by adding code for another event `open` to your existing `.tooltip()` call, something like:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltip({
            position: {
                my: "center top",
                at: "center bottom",
            },
            content: function() {
                 var element = $( this );
                 if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                     return element.attr( "title" );
                 }
                 if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
                     return element.attr( "alt" );
                 }
             },
             open: function (event, ui) {
                 ui.tooltip.css("width", "400px");
            }
    });
```

You can adjust this setting to whatever `width` suits your needs.

Here is an updated jsFiddle to see the result:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4brz0jr8/)

Comment: The jsFiddle link I initially posted did not have my change.  The link has been updated to a jsFiddle that does not contain the change.

Comment: I meant to say: "a jsFiddle that DOES contain the change"